# PyMongo/Mongoengine equivalent of mongodump

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is there an equivalent function in `PyMongo` or `mongoengine` to MongoDB's `mongodump`? I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Use case: I need to periodically backup a remote mongo database. The local machine is a production server that does not have mongo installed, and I do not have admin rights, so I can't use `subprocess` to call `mongodump`. I could install the mongo client locally on a virtualenv, but I'd prefer an API call.

Thanks a lot :-).

Comment: Pymongo and therefore MongoEngine only connect to the `mongod` process.  However, a way around your problem might be to simply run `mongodump` on a remote machine, because you can connect to any remote database with `mongodump/restore` etc.  You don't need to run `mondodump` on the machine that is hosting the db.  Make sense?

Comment: Meh. I guess it's easier to just extract all documents and then build a BSON file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For my relatively small small database, I eventually used the following solution. It's not really suitable for big or complex databases, but it suffices for my case. It dumps all documents as a json to the backup directory. It's clunky, but it does not rely on other stuff than pymongo.

```
from os.path import join
import pymongo
from bson.json_utils import dumps

def backup_db(backup_db_dir):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=<host>, port=<port>)
    database = client[<db_name>]
    authenticated = database.authenticate(<uname>,<pwd>)
    assert authenticated, "Could not authenticate to database!"
    collections = database.collection_names()
    for i, collection_name in enumerate(collections):
        col = getattr(database,collections[i])
        collection = col.find()
        jsonpath = collection_name + ".json"
        jsonpath = join(backup_db_dir, jsonpath)
        with open(jsonpath, 'wb') as jsonfile:
            jsonfile.write(dumps(collection))
```

Comment: thanks for posting this!  Does this differ in any way from cli `mongodump`?  Will the resulting json file be usable with `mongorestore` ?

Comment: You could consider iterating over the result of `col.find()` if you don't intend to hold all the documents in memory at once. You _did_ mention "relatively small small database".

Comment: can we store as bson?

Comment: This should be from bson.json_util import dumps instead of utils.!!!!!!

Comment: I found this solution helpful, but i also want backup in single file. Any suggestions how can i archive in single file as export and import that file to restore database?

Comment: This is good, but will not create `.bson` e `.metadata.json` files. So I think restore using `mongorestore` will not be able.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not working anymore. Here is a revised code:

```
from os.path import join
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

def backup_db(backup_db_dir):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=..., port=..., username=..., password=...)
    database = client[<db_name>]
    collections = database.collection_names()

    for i, collection_name in enumerate(collections):
        col = getattr(database,collections[i])
        collection = col.find()
        jsonpath = collection_name + ".json"
        jsonpath = join(backup_db_dir, jsonpath)
        with open(jsonpath, 'wb') as jsonfile:
            jsonfile.write(dumps(collection).encode())


backup_db('.')
```

Comment: Why do you use .encode here?

Comment: don't remember why I did that, probably because it is written as bytes. Try to remove the encode and see if it works :)

Comment: I believe you don't need it, that's why I was curious. Thank you!

Comment: The collection_names() is deprecated in the version 3.7.0. Instead use database.list_collection_names()