# How to dump a collection to JSON file using Pymongo/json.dumps

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to dump a collection to .json file and looked into previous discussions and the solution doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Link : [How to dump a collection to json file using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153020/how-to-dump-a-collection-to-json-file-using-pymongo)

I am using Python3 and following the solution :

```
import json
import simplejson
from bson.json_util import dumps
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.db_name
collection = db.collection_name

def writeToJSONFile(collection):
   cursor = collection.find({})
   file = open("collection.json", "w")
   file.write('[')

   qnt_cursor = 0
   for document in cursor:
       qnt_cursor += 1
       num_max = cursor.count()
       if (num_max == 1):
           file.write(json.dumps(document, indent=4, default=json_util.default))
       elif (num_max >= 1 and qnt_cursor <= num_max-1):
           file.write(json.dumps(document, indent=4, default=json_util.default))
           file.write(',')
       elif (qnt_cursor == num_max):
           file.write(json.dumps(document, indent=4, default=json_util.default))
   file.write(']')
   return file
```

NameError: name 'json_util' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are importing only son.json_util.dumps
You have to `import bson.json_util`
in order to use  `json_util.default`