# Copying mongo db using pymongo tutorial example fails: "OperationFailure: no such command: 'copydb'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to copy my db for testing purposes. I'm using the [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/copydb.html?highlight=copy) for that, but it still fails:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(username='root', password='pass')
client.admin.command('copydb', fromdb='src', todb='dst')


OperationFailure: no such command: 'copydb', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "no such command: 'copydb'", 'code': 59, 'codeName': 'CommandNotFound'}
```

When trying another command, from [another section of the doc](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command), it worked:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(username='root', password='pass')
db = client.src
db.admin.command('copydb', fromdb='src', todb='dst')
```

The objects used here are different, but this is what the docs say... I still tried using the `db` object for the `copydb` - and failed again:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(username='root', password='pass')
db = client.src
db.admin.command('buildinfo')

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'command' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

which means I use a bad object (makes sense, but I don't get how to make it work)

*pymongo.version: '3.11.0'*
*mongodb version: 4.4.1 (running on docker)*

Comment: Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the copydb command. The deprecated db.copyDatabase(), which wraps the copydb command, can only be run against MongoDB 4.0 or earlier versions.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Comment: @AnuragWagh Saw it now. I'm downgrading and checking (Works!), but surely there is a replacement method for newer versions, no?

Comment: An alternative would be to use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands 
https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#copy-clone-a-database
But `pymongo` doesn't have an API which can `dump` and `restore`

Comment: On the other hand, you can try `os`, `shutil` or `subprocess`  to execute these shell commands 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-an-external-command

Comment: @AnuragWagh I'm not sure this is possible... My host has no `mongod`, only `pymongo`. How could I access the `mongodump` from the host?

Answer (score 0):

Using the help from @AnuragWagh and [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24761633/3512538) I managed to have my own script to handle dump & restore:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
import os
import pymongo


def backup_db(client, db_name, backup_dir):
    if not os.path.isdir(backup_dir):
        os.makedirs(backup_dir)

    database = client[db_name]
    collections = database.list_collection_names()

    for i, collection_name in enumerate(collections):
        col = getattr(database,collections[i])
        collection = col.find()
        jsonpath = collection_name + '.json'

        jsonpath = os.path.join(backup_dir, jsonpath)

        with open(jsonpath, 'wb') as jsonfile:
            jsonfile.write(dumps(collection).encode())


backup_dir = './bckp'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', username='root', password='pass')
src_db_name = 'Jenkins'
dst_db_name = 'Test'
backup_db(client, src_db_name, backup_dir)


for backup_collection in filter(lambda path: path.endswith('.json'), os.listdir(backup_dir)):
    collection_name = backup_collection.rstrip('.json')
    with open(os.path.join(backup_dir, backup_collection), 'rb') as backup_file:
        data = loads(backup_file.read())
        client[dst_db_name][collection_name].insert_many(data)
```

*This is not the ideal solution. If you can, use mongodump & mongorestore. For my case (pymongo on a host without mongodb installed, this seems like the best solution)*